# How do I reduce the latency with android's Volley HTTP GET call response

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Using Volley, I was able to make a asynchronous HTTP GET call to my API that i wanted to hit. But it is taking **15 to 20 seconds** to fetch the data and populate it on the UI, *Staggered Grid Layout using Recycler View*.

For every search call I make, it roughly takes that much time which is *bad*. How do I reduce this latency? I also added the `RequestQueue` but no luck.

I'm initializing the Adapter after the search call is made. Is it a good approach to do it there? Or would you recommend doing it in onCreate method of activity. Could anyone please guide what's the cause for this latency?

Here's the excerpt from the code

```
public class StaggeredSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;
    private StaggeredGridAdapter staggeredGridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_staggered_search);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String searchText = intent.getStringExtra("searchText");
        getSearchData(searchText);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.staggered_recycler_view);
        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    }

    private void getSearchData(String searchText) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        String url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/comments";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    ArrayList<StaggeredCustomCard> dataset = new ArrayList<>();

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                              JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("tweets");
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                String body = jsonObject.getString("body");
                                String postId = jsonObject.getString("postId");
                                dataset.add(new StaggeredCustomCard(body, postId);
                            }
                            staggeredGridAdapter = new StaggeredGridAdapter(StaggeredSearchActivity.this, dataset);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(staggeredGridAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error
                        ...
                    }
                });

        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: How long does it take for the server to respond in postman?

Comment: I just hit the API and I found out it to be the same 20 seconds. @JakeB Is there a way here to reduce the latency by any chance?

Comment: If the latency is that poor, you should look into adding logging on the server to determine what is slowing down the process first.

Comment: Looks like **my-json-server.typicode** offers a free and paid for service. No doubt the paid service has a faster response time but at _$15_ a month you could host your own at a fraction of the cost.

Comment: @Silmarilos got it, thanks!